# How to update the view after an API call (Vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm making a simple shopping cart system with Laravel and Vue. I can successfully add and remove items from the basket. However, when I remove items, I have to refresh the page in order to see the change reflected.

Here's my basket view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price each</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in basketItems">
            <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>&pound;@{{ item.price }}.00</td>
            <td>@{{ item.quantity }}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" v-on:click="removeItem(item.id)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Clicking the delete button calls this function in Vue:

```
 removeItem: function(id){
     this.$http.post('api/buy/removeItem', { id: id });
 }
```

Which then triggers this function in the controller:

```
public function removeItem(Request $request){
     $id = $request->input('id');
     $this->cart->find($id)->remove();
}
```

This all works fine in the background, but the view naturally remains the same. How can I also remove the deleted item from the view?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing just the ID, pass the whole item to the `removeItem` function:

```
v-on:click="removeItem(item)"
```

Then either before or after the API call, remove the item:

```
 removeItem: function(item){
    this.basketItems.$remove(item);
    this.$http.post('api/buy/removeItem', { id: item.id });
 }
```

Or

```
 removeItem: function(item){
    this.$http.post('api/buy/removeItem', { id: item.id })
      .then(function(){
        this.basketItems.$remove(item);
      }.bind(this);
 }
```

Comment: The second would be better since is a sincere reflection of the model.

Comment: @gurghet I agree. The best solution would also give the user feedback that you are removing the item, ie. a loading spinner somewhere, so they know the app is responding to the click.

Comment: I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.basketItems.$remove is not a function
    at Vue.<anonymous> ` (using the second example). Some kind of scope problem maybe?

Comment: Wait! Did you add the `data: { basketItems: [] }` line like I told you in the previous question? If you didn't `basketItems` will not be reactive.

Comment: @gurghet yes, I added it. Is using `this.` not possible when you're inside the `then` function?

Comment: Normally yes. But the error says `this.basketItems` is defined. If unsure, you can try to do the `var _this = this` inside the `then`. Trying won't hurt.

Comment: I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _this is not defined`

Comment: Forget what I said. The `bind` function is probably "binding" the internal `this` to the external `this`

Comment: So what's the solution? :)

Comment: I think the problem may be that the `item` is an object not an array, and it's nested. `{ '535235235' { 'name' : 'widget', 'price' : 20 } }`

Comment: The code should work @flurpleplurple.  Do you get an error if you `$remove` the item first thing, before the `$post` request?

Comment: @jeff I found the solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35464130/6193523. Apparently you can only use `$remove` on an array, not an object.